# ruby 1.9.0 on debian... good choice?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian

I have setup a debian box from scratch and installed ruby1.9 (the one in the repos). I though ruby 1.9.2 would be installed but it was 1.9.0

Well, I keep on with this guy and installed several gems (dm-core among them).

Now, I'm thinking about getting rid of ruby 1.9.0 and install 1.9.2 instead. What is the best and cleanest way to do this kwnowing I'm running debian 5 ?

Will I need to re-installed all the gems ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RVM is by far the best way to do this. See the excellent instructions [here](https://rvm.io)

With RVM I can use multiple installs of Ruby and associated gems in a very effective and easy to use Sandbox. One feature which you may or may not appreciate is that it breaks the link with apt, compiling the source as it requires. I'm using it on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: mccauley, thanks, seems good stuff. once I install ruby 1.9.2 using rvm, do I need to install a new version of rubygems ?

Comment: Glad to be of help! You can find more on RVM and Gem management on the RVM website : http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/

Comment: I finally changed from Debian 5 to Ubuntu 10.04 but used rvm to install 1.9.2. Really great. Cheers.